# How inductance of a coil changes when there is a metal object nearby?

Tags: inductance, detector, metal

I am not sure if it is increasing or decreasing as some sources say it is increasing whereas some say it is not. What actually happens when a metallic object is put under a coil that is meant to be used as a detection coil for metal detector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *What actually happens when a metallic object is put under a coil that
> is meant to be used as a detection coil for metal detector?*

If the metal is (say) iron then there are two opposing effects. Iron has a magnetic permeability much greater than 1 and this will tend to increase the inductance of the search coil but, iron is also a conductor and, it will act as a shorted turn and reduce the inductance of the search coil. Somewhere between the two is the answer and this depends on: -

- Operating frequency
- Relative dimensions of the piece of iron (i.e. shape)
- Size

Incidentally some grades of stainless steel are very difficult to find using a metal detector because the two effects cancel out. I discovered this when designing metal detectors for food and pharmaceutical lines.

For other (non-ferromagnetic) metals/conductors their presence reduces the inductance of the search coil.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the magnetic properties of the object. Some metals are [ferromagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism#Ferromagnetic_materials), some are [paramagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramagnetism), and some are only [diamagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism).

Generally speaking, if the [magnetic permeability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(electromagnetism)) is greater than one (more specifically, if it is greater than that of air), inductance increases; if it is less, inductance decreases.

Comment: you are implicitly assuming that the object is not conductor.